# How do I make it so that a user can only edit/view items belonging to them Using Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I make it so that a user can only edit/view items belonging to them Using Devise? I can't seem to figure it out. I researched and found something on setting up current_user in my checklists controller index and create methods as well as putting the relationship in my users model and checklist model. I am creating a checklist where users can create a title and a name along with adding items to that checklist so I also have a items model. I read about cancan but not quite sure if this is what I am looking for. I just want to be able to have it when a user logs in to create a checklist the list only belongs to them, so when they log out it does not show any checklist they created. When they log back in will show the checklist created. I know it's something fairly simple but cant pin point the task. Can anyone help. I am using rails 4 on this project. Thanks!

Comment: just scope all of your queries under current_user.

`current_user.checlists.all`,  current_users.checklists.find(params[:id]), etc.

Answer (score 2):

There are two main aspects to permissions.  Authentication and Authorization.

Devise provides Authentication, which is basically "this user is this person."  It verifies that through a login.

A library like [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) helps to provide authorization, which is "this user is allowed to do this action."  You can use cancan to [Define an ability with a block](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks) to do something like:

```
can :read, Item, Item.all do |item|
  item.owner == current_user
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, will check into that too.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to write a controller like the following:

```rb
class ChecklistsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_checklist, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @checklists = current_user.checklists
  end

  def new
    @checklist = current_user.checklists.new
  end

  def create
    @checklist = current_user.checklists.create(checklist_params)
  end

  def show
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    @checklist.update_attributes(checklist_params)
    # ...
  end

  def destroy
    @checklist.destroy
    # ...
  end

  private

    def load_checklist
      @checklist = current_user.checklists.find(params[:id])
    end

    def checklist_params
      params.require(:checklist) # .permit(...)
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for info as well. I will check it out later.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a pretty old post but to answer your question, all you need to do is add the filter into your display page. It's an easy fix to what your trying to do.

Here is how you should display your posts if only creator can edit their own posts, it's worked for me to build the functionality quickly.

```html
<tbody>
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= post.content %></td>
        <td> - <%= post.user.username %> (<%= post.user.first_name %> <%= post.user.last_name %>)</td>
        <% if post.user.id == @user %>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Delete', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

in your controller all you need to do is add this line.

```html
@user = current_user.id
```

Sorry it's late but hope it helps others in the future!

You might also need to add the following into your user model.

```html
accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts
```

Answer (score 1):

in your users model:

```
# user.rb

has_many :items #or somehow like this if you have joins or something else
```

in controller:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user! #inherit devise helpers and methods in controller

def index
  @items = current_user.items #for the current !!signed-in!! user

  # other necessary code...
end

def edit
  @item = current_user.items.find(params[:id])

  # other necessary code... show action would include the same row for @item finding 
end
```

can-can gem is really you can use too in case you have a lot of authorization issues not just you mentioned... there are a lot of tutorials around and not the worst one is within cancan documentation

Comment: Thanks! I was doing something to this similar today and was getting some errors. Will check it out later when I get home.

Comment: just post errors you have i believe we will find solution quickly

Comment: Hey Okliv, I did the above in the neccessary controller and updated the models but keep getting this error. undefined method `checklists' for nil:NilClass. Can't seem to figure out why. I updated my index controller and edit and show actions in the controller as you suggested but no luck.

Comment: and just shot into the air: do you have `before_filter :authenticate_user!` in your controller?

Comment: in my checklist controller                                before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :delete]

Comment: `except: [:index, :delete]` - index... ? and you should better append user model code to question - maybe it helps someone to help you :)

Comment: last two places where i can imagine problem can hide are device.rb initializer (`config.default_scope = :user` option) and routes.rb (`devise_for :users`)

Comment: Sorry and Thanks! I'm having trouble posting the users.rb model for some reason I can't seem to indent 4 spaces to post the coding correctly. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: definitely =) just make an empty row between each paragraph of your text and you will see that formatting applies correctly to your indented part of text (with code)

Answer (score 1):

> you have to put user_id foreign key in all those models where you want
>   to put this restriction.
>
> and the edit and view action do something like this
>
> example : -
>
> user has_many :posts
>
> and post belong_to :user

```
def edit
  @post = current_user.posts.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @post = current_user.posts.find(params[:id])
  @post.update_attributes(params[:id])
  respond_with @post
end


def show
  @post = current_user.posts.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try working it this way as well. I know I am in the right direction but can't get there.